# Redirecting from old to new site, changing canonical adress

Tags: url, redirect

I have never done redirecting and such stuff.
I have site A: www.sitea.org.

This site had to change the branding, name, logo, url etc.
So i bought a new domain B: www.siteb.org.

They are on different hostings. I copied all the files from sitea, to siteb.
On siteb I changed the names. So now they almost have exact content, expect the names.

When someone searched for content on sitea over google, that sitea would appear high in google ranking. Now the problem is, I want when someone googles that content again, that the new url appears www.siteb.org.

How can I do that?!
Should I delete the content from the server of sitea?

Comment: https://www.square2marketing.com/blog/how-to-change-domain-names-not-lose-seo

Comment: is your website based on CMS or Framwork ?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj old website is simple html. New site is php. No CMS's or Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, modify your first site to send a `301` to new site for all the urls. Next, you need to tell google about the change in address as described [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en). Finally be patient. It would take somedays to get the change reflected.

Comment: the 301 I can setup over cPanel, and I need it to do for every subpage from sitea to siteb?

Comment: Yes. You can do this by configuring your server `nginx` or `apache` to write all the urls by changing the hostname. This would redirect all the routes. Redirecting all the routes is important because, when any search engine(like google) crawls your any link and finds the 301, it would record them. So its a must to do for all the urls.

Comment: Alright, the redirects are fine. Should I add canonical links to all sites on the old domain to point to new one? I mean beacuse of google search etc.?